# Not able to display data in detail page using splitcontainer in sapui5?

Tags: sapui5, splitcontainer, element-binding

I am using splitcontainer in my application. I used two views one for Master page and other one for detail page.

This is my view code: Main.view.xml(which holds Master and detail views)

```
    <SplitContainer id="idSplitContainer">
            <masterPages>
            <mvc:XMLView id="master" viewName="com.test.view.Master"/>
            </masterPages>
            <detailPages>
            <mvc:XMLView id="detail" viewName="com.test.view.Detail"/>
            </detailPages>
        </SplitContainer>
```

**Master.view.xml:**

```
<ScrollContainer height="35rem" width="100%" horizontal="false" vertical="true" focusable="false">

<Table  id="listTable" inset="false" items="{ path: 'testModel>/testCollection'}" fixedLayout="false">
<columns>
    <Column>
    <Text text=" Number"/></Column>
    <Column>
    <Text text="Description"/>  </Column>
    <Column>
    <Text text="Status"/>
    </Column>
    </columns>
    <items>
    <ColumnListItem  vAlign="Middle" type="Navigation" press="onSelectionChange">                   
    <cells>
    <Text text="{testModel>Number}" wrapping="false"/>
    <Text text="{testModel>Description}" wrapping="false"/>
    <Text text="{testModel>Status}" wrapping="false"/>
    </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
    </items>
    </Table>

  </ScrollContainer>
```

Detail.view.xml

```
<mvc:View controllerName=com.test.controller.Detail" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form"  xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:commons="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
<form:Form >
<form:layout>
<form:ResponsiveGridLayout columnsM="1" columnsL="1" labelSpanL="2" labelSpanM="2" emptySpanL="2" emptySpanM="2" />
</form:layout>
<form:formContainers>
<form:FormContainer>
    <form:formElements>
    <form:FormElement>
        <form:fields>
        <Label id="DescriptionLabel" text="Description" />
            <Input value="{testModel>Description}"></Input>
        </form:fields>
    </form:FormElement>
        </form:formElements>
        </form:FormContainer>   
    </form:formContainers>
    </form:Form>

</mvc:View>
```

**Component.js**

```
    routing: {
    config: {
        routerClass: "sap.m.routing.Router",
        viewPath: "com.test.view",
        controlId: "SplitContainer",
        viewType: "XML",
        async: true
        },
        routes: [{
            name: "master",
            pattern: "",
            target: ["master"]
            }, {
            name: "testDetails",
            pattern: "test/:Number:",
            target: ["testDetails"]
            }],
        targets: {
            master: {
            viewName: "Master",
            controlAggregation: "masterPages",
            viewLevel: 0
            },
        testDetails: {
            viewName: "Detail",
            controlAggregation: "detailPages",
            viewLevel: 1
            }
        }
    },
var sampleData = {
        "testCollection": [{
         "Description": "Test Description1",
         "Status": "Completed",
        "Number":10021
        }, {
        "Description": "Test Description2",
        "Status": "Completed",
        "Number":10025
}
]
};
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(sampleData);
this.setModel(oModel,"testModel");
```

I am setting model in component level and i am using in both Master and Detail views.

**Master.controller.js**

```
onSelectionChange: function (oEvent) {
   var sNum = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("testModel").getObject().Number;
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("testDetails", {
                        Number: sNum
                    }, false);
            }
```

**Detail.controller.js:**

```
onInit: function() {  
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("testDetails").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this); 
   },
_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
this._sNum = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Number;
this.getView().bindElement("testModel>/testCollection/"+this._sNum);    
}
```

Problem:

I am not able to display the details of a selected table row in Detail view.

Please guide me on this.
[image]

Comment: any error displayed in the Chrome Dev Tool's console?

Comment: for the master detail realtionship you should use the flexible comlumn layout please check the designguidelines https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/

Comment: @Erch earlier we were using unified SplitContainer , since it is deprecated. We are using m SplitContainer

Comment: as I said if you want to follow sap standards you will need to use the flexible column layout, if not there might be less ppl willing to look into the problem

Comment: Not sure if this was an error from copying an pasting into StackOverflow but there is an error on the first line of your detail view, an unclosed quote for the "controllerName"

Answer (score 0):

The reason mostly is due to the way you are using `bindElement`. The statement `"testModel>/testCollection/"+this._sNum` is not clear. Try the following,

In the Master controller's function `onSelectionChange` do this,

`onSelectionChange: function (oEvent) {
var sContextPath = oEvent.getSource().getBindingContext("testModel").getPath();
this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("testDetails", {
                        Path: sContextPath
                    }, false);
            }`

Next in the Detail controller's function `_onRouteMatched` do this,

`_onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
this.getView().bindElement({path: oEvent.getParameter("arguments").Path , model: "testModel"}); 
}`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with a few changes to Main/Master Views, Sample Data and both controllers. The main issues were in your master view and data. Here is a working [Plnkr](https://embed.plnkr.co/R39r3JFigeUXyV6SWT9i/) or see below:

In **Manifest.json** or your **Component.js**

```js
"routing": {
  "config": {
    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
    "viewPath": "com.test.view",
    "controlId": "rootControl",
    "viewType": "XML",
    "async": true,
    "bypassed": {
      "target": ["master"]
    }
  },
  "routes": [{
    "name": "master",
    "pattern": "",
    "target": ["master"]
  }, {
    "name": "detail",
    "pattern": "testCollection/:detailID:", <<Change
    "target": ["master", "detail"]
  }],
  "targets": {
    "master": {
      "viewName": "Master",
      "controlAggregation": "masterPages",
      "viewLevel": "0"
    },
    "detail": {
      "viewName": "Detail",
      "controlAggregation": "detailPages",
      "viewLevel": "1"
    }
  }
}
```

In **master.view.xml**, I would advice you not to use a table as your master but a List instead:

```html
<mvc:View controllerName="com.test.controller.Detail" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
  <semantic:MasterPage id="page" title="Contents">
    <semantic:content>
      <ScrollContainer height="35rem" width="100%" horizontal="false" vertical="true" focusable="false">
        <List id="list" items="{testModel>/testCollection}" mode="SingleSelectMaster" noDataText="No List Found" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" selectionChange="onSelectionChange" updateFinished="onUpdateFinished">
          <items>
            <StandardListItem title="{testModel>Description}" type="Active" press="onSelectionChange" description="{testModel>Number}" />
          </items>
        </List> <!--List instead of a table -->
        </ScrollContainer>
    </semantic:content>
  </semantic:MasterPage>
</mvc:View>
```

In your **Master.controller.js**, few changes, mainly by adding the `.getSelectedItem()` method (does not work on mobile Device):

```js
onInit: function() {
    this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("master").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
  },
  _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) { //<<Inital
    if (!Device.system.phone) {
      this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter()
        .navTo("detail", {
          detailID: 0 
        }, true);
    }
  },
  onSelectionChange: function(oEvent) {
    var sNum = oEvent.getSource().getSelectedItem().getBindingContext("testModel").getProperty("id"); //<<selectedItem using id

    this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().navTo("detail", {
      detailID: sNum 
    }, false);
  }
```

In **Detail.view.xml**, that can stay the same or add a semantic tag:

```html
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:layout="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:form="sap.ui.layout.form" controllerName="com.test.controller.Detail" xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic">
  <semantic:DetailPage id="page" title="{i18n>detailTitle}" navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <semantic:content>
      <form:Form>
        <form:layout>
          <form:ResponsiveGridLayout columnsM="1" columnsL="1" labelSpanL="2" labelSpanM="2" emptySpanL="2" emptySpanM="2" />
        </form:layout>
        <form:formContainers>
          <form:FormContainer>
            <form:formElements>
              <form:FormElement>
                <form:fields>
                  <Label id="DescriptionLabel" text="Description" />
                  <Input value="{testModel>Description}"></Input>
                </form:fields>
              </form:FormElement>
            </form:formElements>
          </form:FormContainer>
        </form:formContainers>
      </form:Form>
    </semantic:content>
  </semantic:DetailPage>
</mvc:View> <!--same but with semanticpage attribute -->
```

In your **Detail.controller.js**

```js
onInit: function() {
    this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter().getRoute("detail").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
  },
  _onRouteMatched: function(oEvent) {
    this._sNum = oEvent.getParameter("arguments").detailID;
    this.getView().bindElement({
      path: "/testCollection/" + this._sNum,
      model: "testModel"
    });
  }
```

And a tiny addition to **data.json** or your **Component.js** tracking by ID:

```js
{
  "testCollection": [{
    "id": 0, //<<tracked by id 
    "Description": "Test Description1",
    "Status": "Completed",
    "Number": 10021
  }, {
    "id": 1,
    "Description": "Test Description2",
    "Status": "Completed",
    "Number": 10025
  }]
}
```